# N1QL index for multiple json object

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I would like to get digest field from test attribute. Attribute test can change for each of documents.

attachments field is having json object instead of array of json object.
I would like to create index which should give digest field which is inside `_sync.attachments.test.digest`

Please help in index and query in getting digest field.

```
{
  "_sync": {
    "attachments": {
      "test": {
        "content_type": "text/html",
        "digest": "sha1-CMKBiqaqoO++IxKQxH5ZW5smywY=",
        "length": 10240,
        "revpos": 3,
        "stub": true
      }
    },
    "time": "2019-10-14T05:38"
  }
}
```

Comment: What indexes have you tried? Have you looked at any of the indexing documentation?